# Problems with using a windows service to invoke a java program using JNI and LoadLibrary

Tags: java, c, windows, service, java-native-interface

I'm creating a windows service program which invokes a java program.

Here is part of the code, hModule is a global variable and LoadLibrary is called in ServiceStart after which it invoked invokeJVM. I manage to start the service and it runs fine, however, whenever I stop the service, it gives me an error:
Windows could not stop the service on the local computer
Error 1067: The windows service terminated unexpectedly

After adding additional logging, I found that the place where the unexpected termination error occurs is the return of the invokeJVM function.
When I check the event viewer it gives me some BEX error, which on googling, says that it is a stack overflow error, but I could not determine the cause of it, any idea why?

```
HMODULE hModule;

VOID ServiceStart ( DWORD dwArgc, LPTSTR *lpszArgv )
{
    // Let the service control manager know that the service is
    // initializing.
    if ( !ReportStatus( SERVICE_START_PENDING, NO_ERROR, 3000 ) )
        //goto cleanup;
        return;

    hModule = LoadLibrary( TEXT( "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll" ) );

    // Create a Stop Event
    if ( !( hServerStopEvent = CreateEvent( NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL) ) )
        goto cleanup;

    lpszJavaArgs = getJavaArgs( &lpszJavaArgs, &dwJLen, dwArgc, lpszArgv );
    lpszAppArgs = getAppArgs( &lpszAppArgs, &dwALen, dwArgc, lpszArgv );
    wrkdir = getWorkingDirectory( dwArgc, lpszArgv );

    if ( !ReportStatus( SERVICE_RUNNING, NO_ERROR, 0 ) )
        goto cleanup;

    // After the initialization is complete (we've checked for arguments) and
    // the service control manager has been told the service is running, invoke
    // the Java application. If clients are unable to access 
    // the server, check the event log for messages that should indicate any errors
    // that may have occured while firing up Java...

    invokeJVM( NULL );

    // Wait for the stop event to be signalled.
    WaitForSingleObject( hServerStopEvent, INFINITE );

cleanup:
    ( VOID ) ReportStatus( SERVICE_STOPPED, 0, 0 );
    if ( hServerStopEvent )
        CloseHandle( hServerStopEvent );
    ( *vm ) -> DestroyJavaVM( vm );
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread( hModule, 0 );

    return;
}

VOID invokeJVM( VOID *dummy )
{
    jint res;
    jclass cls;
    jmethodID mid;
    jstring jstr;
    jobjectArray args;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[ MAX_OPTIONS ];
    jint ( *createJavaVM )( JavaVM **, void **, void * ) = 
        ( jint ( * )( JavaVM **, void **, void * ) ) GetProcAddress( hModule, "JNI_CreateJavaVM" );
    char buf[256];
    jclass cls2;
    jmethodID mid2;
    UINT uIdx;

    if ( wrkdir )
    {
        if ( !SetCurrentDirectory( wrkdir ) )
            AddToMessageLog( TEXT( "Unable to change working directory." ) );
    }

    if(dwJLen > MAX_OPTIONS)
    {
        AddToMessageLog( TEXT( "Max. number of Java args exceeded." ) );
        return;
    }

    // Assign the arguments for the JVM, such as the classpath,
    // RMI codebase, etc.
    for ( uIdx = 0; uIdx < dwJLen; ++uIdx )
        options[ uIdx ].optionString = lpszJavaArgs[ uIdx ]; // PROBLEM HERE

    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.nOptions = dwJLen;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = TRUE;

    //res = JNI_CreateJavaVM( &vm, ( void ** ) &env, &vm_args );
    res = ( *createJavaVM )( &vm, ( void ** ) &env, &vm_args );
    if ( res < 0 )
    {
        AddToMessageLog( TEXT( "Cannot create Java VM." ) );
        return;
    }

    // Get the main class
    if ( !( cls = ( *env ) -> FindClass( env, SZMAINCLASS ) ) )
    {
        AddToMessageLog( TEXT( "Cannot find main class." ) );
        return;
    }

    // Get the method ID for the class's main(String[]) function. 
    if ( !( mid = ( *env ) -> GetStaticMethodID( env, cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V" ) ) )
    {
        AddToMessageLog( TEXT( "Cannot find main method." ) );
        return;
    }

    // If there are arguments, create an ObjectArray sized to contain the
    // argument list, and then scan the list, inserting each argument into
    // the ObjectArray.
    if( dwALen > 0 )
    {
        if ( !( args = ( *env ) -> NewObjectArray( env, dwALen, ( *env ) -> FindClass( env, "java/lang/String" ), NULL ) ) ) 
        {
            AddToMessageLog( TEXT( "Out of Memory!" ) );
            return;
        }

        for( uIdx = 0; uIdx < dwALen; ++uIdx )
        {
            if ( !( jstr = ( *env ) -> NewStringUTF( env, lpszAppArgs[ uIdx ] ) ) )
            {
                AddToMessageLog( TEXT( "Out of Memory!" ) );
                return;
            }
            ( *env ) -> SetObjectArrayElement( env, args, uIdx, jstr );
        }
    }
    // Otherwise, create an empty array. This is needed to avoid
    // creating an overloaded main that takes no arguments in the Java
    // app, and then getting a different method ID to the no-argument
    // main() method in this invoker code.
    else
    {
        args = ( *env ) -> NewObjectArray( env, 0, ( *env ) -> FindClass( env, "java/lang/String" ), NULL );
    }

    //Now, get the class of the java SCMEventManager
    if ( !( cls2 = ( *env ) -> FindClass( env, SZSCMEVENTMANAGER ) ) )
    {
        AddToMessageLog( TEXT( "Cannot find SCMEventManager class." ) );
        goto finished;
    }

    //Get the method ID for SCMEventManager.getInstance()
    sprintf( buf, "()L%s;", SZSCMEVENTMANAGER );
    if ( !( mid2 = ( *env ) -> GetStaticMethodID( env, cls2, "getInstance", buf ) ) )
    {
        AddToMessageLog( TEXT( "Cannot find SCMEventManager.getInstance." ) );
        goto finished;
    }

    //Call SCMEventManager.getInstance() and save the returned object
    //We'll use this later on.

    if ( !( jobj = ( *env ) -> NewGlobalRef( env, ( *env ) -> CallStaticObjectMethod( env, cls2, mid2 ) ) ) )
    {
        AddToMessageLog( TEXT( "Cannot call SCMEventManager.getInstance." ) );
        goto finished;
    }

finished:
    // Run the main class...
    ( *env ) -> CallStaticVoidMethod( env, cls, mid, args );
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler( logoffHandler, TRUE );

    return;
}
```

Comment: The posted source for `invokeJVM()` is somehow incomplete (for (;;) statements and at least one missing bracket somewhere)

Comment: Seems complete to me, it compiles fine, which is the exact statement or region which you refer to?

Comment: The first curly bracket after `SetObjectArrayElement()` seems orphaned and the two `for (uIdx = 0; uIdx ...;)` are incomplete.

Comment: for( uIdx = 0; uIdx < dwALen; ++uIdx )
  {
   if ( !( jstr = ( *env ) -> NewStringUTF( env, lpszAppArgs[ uIdx ] ) ) )
   {
    AddToMessageLog( TEXT( "Out of Memory!" ) );
    return;
   }
   ( *env ) -> SetObjectArrayElement( env, args, uIdx, jstr );
  }

Comment: Sorry, the exact code is the above comment, I can't seem to get it to display above, when I select edit the if statement is there but when it appears, on screen the if doesn't show

Comment: I asked a Mod to correct the issue with the code not displayed. And obviously he did. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be using the wrong calling convention. What happens if you try something like this:

```
jint (__stdcall *createJavaVM )( JavaVM **, void **, void * ) = ( jint ( __stdcall * )( JavaVM **, void **, void * ) ) GetProcAddress( hModule, "JNI_CreateJavaVM" );
```

P.S.
If it's not stdcall, find out which one is it.

Comment: How do I find out which calling convention it is?

Comment: Ok buddy, you earned your 50 rep points, but I still have a few questions,
Q1) let's say I do not know which calling convention it is, how do I find out?
Q2) How did you know the cause was calling convention, was it because of the stack overflow which would occur if the arguments were pushed and popped wrongly on the stack?

Comment: Check the jvm/jni's dll's export table. If the symbol `createJavaVM` has an `@xx` suffix, then it's stdcall. Otherwise, it's cdecl.

Comment: Sorry if this might be a stupid question but how do I check the dll export table?

Comment: Calling convention did cross my mind when I saw in your question this: "When I check the event viewer it gives me some BEX error...". Usually __cdecl is the default calling convention (originally used by your code) and initialization functions exported by DLL are usually __stdcall. Anyway, while writing this comment as a reply to your second question on how to find out which calling convention is it, I also found this: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/download/jni.pdf. It says that JNI_CreateJavaVM uses JNI calling convention, which is the standard Win32 calling convention (stdcall).

Comment: Regarding Q1, how to find out which calling convention is it generally... right at this moment nothing comes to me... I guess the DLL creator should provide such information. The other "hard core" approach that comes to me is reverse engineering and looking at the asm code. That will give you a direct answer. You can see the exported functions with the dumpbin /exports command line tool by MS. e.g. Run Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt and you can use it.